# Why does cross-correlation involve the complex conjugate?

Tags: signal-processing

The cross-correlation of continuous $f,g$ is:

$(f \star g)(\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^*(t)g(t+\tau)dt$

where * is the complex conjugate.

Why is there the complex conjugate?

Comment: One desirable property that comes from using the complex conjugate is that $(f\star f)(0)\geq 0$

Comment: Isn't the integration made on transformed functions?